# Can you build a Obsidian generator in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am currently working on building stone and cobblestone generators in Minecraft, but I am wondering if you can build an obsidian generator. Is there a way (hopefully similar to the cobblestone generator) that I can build one?

Comment: depends on what you mean by generator, if you mean the same as a cobble generator, then i dont think so as you cant make an infinite lava source. grabbing lava from the nether and dumping it into water generates obby, but i dont think thats what you mean

Comment: If someone could explain their close vote a bit more that would be good. What's unclear about this? You can instantly tell what the question is just by the title, although maybe the body needs a bit of fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **there is no way to make an infinite obsidian generator**, as obsidian requires a lava source block, and there is no way to infinitely create this, as it's game mechanics are different from those of water, and it can't flow infinitely. But, you can still create obsidian by simply pouring water over lava source blocks.